# How to represent The SQL query in Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have simple query in SQL but find difficulty in converting in linq. I am new to the linq.

My SQL select Statement is as follows

```
select CM.CategoryName 
from dbo.utblCategoryMaster as CM 
where CM.ParentCategoryID in 
   (select CategoryID from dbo.utblCategoryMaster where CategoryName='Events')
```

I know this is simple and easy. I have tried this

```
var result = from objutblCategoryMaster in db.utblCategoryMasters
  select new
  {
      CategoryID = objutblCategoryMaster.CategoryID,
      CategoryName = db.utblCategoryMasters.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryID == objutblCategoryMaster.CategoryID && x.CategoryName=="Events")
  };
return result.CopyToDataTableExt();
```

Comment: what is your exact question Chettri

Comment: I find difficulty in converting my sql query in linq. I just want to convert my sql query to linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result with a join.

```
var result = db.utblCategoryMasters
               .Join(db.utblCategoryMasters.Where(c => c.CategoryName=="Events"),
                   cm => cm.ParentCategoryId,
                   c => c.CategoryId,
                   (cm, c) => new { cm.CategoryId, cm.CategoryName });
```

If you're using Entity Framework and the navigation properties are set up properly, you can simplify it to something like this...

```
var result = db.utblCategoryMasters
                 .Where(cm => cm.ParentCategory.CategoryName == "Events")
                 .Select(cm => new { cm.CategoryId, cm.CategoryName });
```